# Why does the performance lack in the Bitmap Index Scan?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I have the following sub query that is taking quite some time to execute.

I also put the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` at http://explain.depesz.com/s/JD4 It seems it takes longest at the `Bitmap Index Scan`.

Can anyone provide some pointers on how to optimize this query.

```
foobar_production=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
foobar_production->   date_trunc('day', c.time_at) AS time_at,
foobar_production->   COUNT(*) as count
foobar_production-> FROM (
foobar_production(> SELECT
foobar_production(>   ds.user_id,
foobar_production(>   max(case when id=maxid then country_id end) AS country_id,
foobar_production(>   max(case when id=maxid then time_at end) AS time_at,
foobar_production(>   max(case when id=maxid then properties->'assumed_gender' end) AS assumed_gender,
foobar_production(>   json_agg(to_json(attachment_id)) AS attachment_ids
foobar_production(> FROM daily_statistics ds JOIN (
foobar_production(>     SELECT u.id as user_id, (
foobar_production(>       SELECT ds2.id FROM daily_statistics ds2 WHERE ds2.user_id=u.id AND ds2.metric = 'participation' AND ds2.status = 'active' AND ds2.campaign_id = 4742
foobar_production(>       ORDER BY ds2.id DESC LIMIT 1
foobar_production(>     ) AS maxid FROM users u
foobar_production(>     WHERE u.properties -> 'provider' IN ('twitter')
foobar_production(> ) mu ON (ds.user_id=mu.user_id)
foobar_production(> WHERE ds.campaign_id = 4742 AND ds.metric = 'participation' AND ds.status = 'active'
foobar_production(> GROUP BY ds.user_id
foobar_production(> ) AS c
foobar_production-> GROUP BY date_trunc('day', c.time_at)
foobar_production-> ORDER BY time_at DESC
foobar_production-> LIMIT 7;


                                                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=2059.51..2059.54 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=19557.814..19558.392 rows=7 loops=1)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=2059.51..2059.54 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=19557.807..19558.377 rows=7 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=2059.51..2059.52 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=19557.786..19558.070 rows=374 loops=1)
               Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, c.time_at))
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 60kB
               ->  Subquery Scan on c  (cost=2059.48..2059.50 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=19554.953..19557.062 rows=751 loops=1)
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2059.48..2059.49 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=19554.919..19555.804 rows=751 loops=1)
                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..1880.45 rows=2 width=103) (actual time=0.725..229.637 rows=2721 loops=1)
                                 ->  Index Scan using index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type on daily_statistics ds  (cost=0.56..1618.19 rows=31 width=99) (actual time=0.168..25.245 rows=9557 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: (campaign_id = 4742)
                                       Filter: (((metric)::text = 'participation'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'active'::text))
                                 ->  Index Scan using index_users_on_id_and_type on users u  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=0 loops=9557)
                                       Index Cond: (id = ds.user_id)
                                       Filter: ((properties -> 'provider'::text) = 'twitter'::text)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                           SubPlan 1
                             ->  Limit  (cost=29.83..29.83 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.438..2.439 rows=1 loops=2721)
                                   ->  Sort  (cost=29.83..29.83 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.433..2.433 rows=1 loops=2721)
                                         Sort Key: ds2.id
                                         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on daily_statistics ds2  (cost=25.80..29.82 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.890..2.213 rows=107 loops=2721)
                                               Recheck Cond: ((user_id = u.id) AND (campaign_id = 4742))
                                               Filter: (((metric)::text = 'participation'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'active'::text))
                                               ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=25.80..25.80 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1.879..1.879 rows=0 loops=2721)
                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..5.60 rows=156 width=0) (actual time=0.076..0.076 rows=297 loops=2721)
                                                           Index Cond: (user_id = u.id)
                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type  (cost=0.00..19.95 rows=452 width=0) (actual time=1.770..1.770 rows=9557 loops=2721)
                                                           Index Cond: (campaign_id = 4742)
                           SubPlan 2
                             ->  Limit  (cost=29.83..29.83 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.320..2.321 rows=1 loops=2721)
                                   ->  Sort  (cost=29.83..29.83 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.318..2.318 rows=1 loops=2721)
                                         Sort Key: ds2_1.id
                                         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on daily_statistics ds2_1  (cost=25.80..29.82 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.859..2.112 rows=107 loops=2721)
                                               Recheck Cond: ((user_id = u.id) AND (campaign_id = 4742))
                                               Filter: (((metric)::text = 'participation'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'active'::text))
                                               ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=25.80..25.80 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1.838..1.838 rows=0 loops=2721)
                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..5.60 rows=156 width=0) (actual time=0.092..0.092 rows=297 loops=2721)
                                                           Index Cond: (user_id = u.id)
                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type  (cost=0.00..19.95 rows=452 width=0) (actual time=1.713..1.713 rows=9557 loops=2721)
                                                           Index Cond: (campaign_id = 4742)
                           SubPlan 3
                             ->  Limit  (cost=29.83..29.83 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.309..2.310 rows=1 loops=2721)
                                   ->  Sort  (cost=29.83..29.83 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.300..2.300 rows=1 loops=2721)
                                         Sort Key: ds2_2.id
                                         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on daily_statistics ds2_2  (cost=25.80..29.82 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.802..2.069 rows=107 loops=2721)
                                               Recheck Cond: ((user_id = u.id) AND (campaign_id = 4742))
                                               Filter: (((metric)::text = 'participation'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'active'::text))
                                               ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=25.80..25.80 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1.785..1.785 rows=0 loops=2721)
                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..5.60 rows=156 width=0) (actual time=0.073..0.073 rows=297 loops=2721)
                                                           Index Cond: (user_id = u.id)
                                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type  (cost=0.00..19.95 rows=452 width=0) (actual time=1.680..1.680 rows=9557 loops=2721)
                                                           Index Cond: (campaign_id = 4742)
 Total runtime: 19558.785 ms
(55 rows)
```

EDIT. Here is the table structure (columns and indices):

```
foobar_production=> \d daily_statistics;
                                       Table "public.daily_statistics"
    Column     |            Type             |                           Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('daily_statistics_id_seq'::regclass)
 type          | character varying(255)      |
 metric        | character varying(255)      |
 campaign_id   | integer                     |
 user_id       | integer                     |
 country_id    | integer                     |
 attachment_id | integer                     |
 time_at       | timestamp without time zone |
 properties    | hstore                      |
 status        | character varying(255)      | default 'active'::character varying
Indexes:
    "daily_statistics_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_attachment_id" btree (attachment_id)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type" btree (campaign_id, type)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_country_id" btree (country_id)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_id" btree (id)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_metric" btree (metric)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_properties" gin (properties)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_status" btree (status)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_time_at" btree (time_at)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

Comment: Are you open to creating new or other indices? What are the current indices?

Comment: @nvoigt Yeap, open to new / other indices. I edited the SO question to include the indices via `\d daily_statistics;`

Comment: Consider re-runnning after `SET sort_mem = '10MB'` or similar, see if it'll chose a different (more memory-hungry but potentially faster) plan. Also, what are the `random_page_cost` and `seq_page_cost` settings? Does varying `random_page_cost` with `SET` cause plans to be chosen that land up being faster?

Comment: @CraigRinger `sort_mem': 1mb, `random_page_cost`: 4, `seq_page_cost`: 1. I am using a AWS RDS instance: `db.m3.medium`. I don't think I will be able to modify those settings without having to upgrade to a better instance.

Comment: In AWS RDS, `sort_mem` is known as `work_mem`. I changed the value from 1mb to 10mb. Not much of a difference

Comment: At this point, is there a better way to write this query? Perhaps via a lateral join?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini @ChristianFazzini @ChristianFazzini Ugh, it's `work_mem` in stock PostgreSQL too, i just had a brain moment. If you use RDS you should mention in the question or tags. You should still be able to SET interactively.